# Setting up github actions SQL linting

Tags: python, github, github-actions, lint, sqlfluff

I am trying to setup a simple github actions workflow for sql linting using sqlfluff package. [here](https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff-github-actions/tree/main/menu_of_workflows/sunrise_movement) is `sunrise movement` workflow which is simple and clean.

```
name: Lint Models

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  lint-models:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: "actions/checkout@v2"
      - uses: "actions/setup-python@v2"
        with:
            python-version: "3.8"
      - name: Install SQLFluff
        run: "pip install sqlfluff==0.12.0"
      - name: Lint models
        run: "sqlfluff lint models"
```

When I tried to run it in github actions, it is giving me the following error message. Not quite sure why it is throwing error. Help is appreciated as I am trying to learn github acitons for the first time.
[image: Error]

Comment: There is no file or folder called `models`. Neither is it created in your workflow nor is it part of your repository (would be created on the runner in the checkout step).

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
        run: "sqlfluff lint models"
```

This says to lint the directory called `models`. The directory does not exist in your repo (is it a sub folder?).